# Powershell script output to Discord

Tags: powershell, discord

*removing source for Proprietary reasons*

ERROR

Out-String : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At line:176 char:28

- ```
  content = $summaries | Out-String `
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: **This isn't a complete answer**, but it addresses your immediate problem - broken `[pscustomobject]` literal syntax - and provides some background information.

[`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table), as all `Format-*` cmdlets, is only intended to produce output *for display* as opposed to *programmatic processing*.

To produce *data* (objects), use the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object), which uses the same syntax with respect to the `-Property` parameter as `Format-Table`, notably including the [calculated properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) your `Format-Table` call uses.

`Select-Object` outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances that each have the specified properties.

Thus, you *may* be looking for this:

```bash
# Note The ` at the end of the line continues the Select-Object call
# on the next line, and the following lines are an array of 
# property names / calculated properties that are passed 
# to the positionally implied -Property parameter
$payload = $summaries | Select-Object `
    start, 
    end, 
    @{ Label = 'issued_amount';          Expression = { '{0:C0}'     -f $_.issued_amount              }; Align = 'right' },
    @{ Label = 'maturing_amount';        Expression = { '{0:C0}'     -f $_.maturing_amount            }; Align = 'right' }, 
    @{ Label = 'inflation_compensation'; Expression = { '{0:C0}'     -f $_.inflation_compensation     }; Align = 'right' }, 
    @{ Label = 'secondary_purchased';    Expression = { '{0:C0}'     -f $_.secondary_purchased_amount }; Align = 'right' }, 
    @{ Label = 'secondary_sold';         Expression = { '{0:C0}'     -f $_.secondary_sold_amount      }; Align = 'right' }, 
    @{ Label = 'change';                 Expression = { '{0:$#,##0}' -f $_.change                     }; Align = 'right' }
```

`$payload` is now an array of `[pscustomobject]` instances with the specified properties.

However, it looks like you cannot pass such an array directly to [`Send-DiscordMessage`](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSDiscord), except perhaps via the `-Text` parameter, which requires you to create a formatted *string* representation via [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string):

```bash
Send-DiscordMessage -Uri $hookUrl -Text ($payload | Out-String)
```

Comment: BRILLIANT, thank you so much. i had to remove align and then remove other sections as it reached word cap but it works. i can't thank you enough, 20+ hours banging my head trying to get this to work and i was seriously ready to give up.

Comment: I am glad to hear it, @nbdyso; my pleasure.